# How should I use my humidifier's bypass option?

Tags: hvac

I have a [Skuttle model 2000](http://skuttle.com/wp1/?page_id=158) flow-through bypass humidifier unit. How do I use the bypass lever in the winter months? Do I leave the bypass open during operation and closed in the summer months??

Answer (score 1):

From [the website](http://skuttle.com/wp1/?page_id=158):

> The summer shutoff damper on bypass units increases efficiency and saves energy. [...] The humidifier and the connecting water valve must be turned OFF at the end of each heating season. On bypass units, the shutoff damper should be turned to SUMMER.

More in the [owner's manual](http://skuttle.com/wp1/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/2000-01-02-Owner-Pages_eng.fr_.sp_2013.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t have air conditioning it won’t matter, just leave it open all the time. If you have air conditioning it is a good idea to close the bypass in the summer since it is bypassing some air around the coil loosing some capacity and efficiency.